# Unable to deploy OLAP cube

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssas, cube

I am trying to deploy a cube on SQL Server 2008 using MS Visual Studio 2005 and I am getting the following error.

[Connection Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKe1S.png)

Does anyone know why this is happening? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I checked these different solutions.
[Venkattechinalblog](http://venkattechnicalblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/cannot-connect-to-analysis-services.html)

1. May be ur SSAS port is blocking( add port 2383 to the SQL Server Connections in the Windows Firewall.)
2. Ensure your SSAS services and Browser services is running fine in Services.msc console.
3. Right click on the project properties and check the deployment server as your server name instead of "local host"
4. Finally :-) Do not open your project in Microsoft Visual studio console. Instead try to open the BIDS tool to deploy your cubes. Some how, SSAS is not allowing the users to deploy the cubes from this console. (here is the mistake, I have done) Fortunately resolved it.